# Rows from cross-server query on SQL Server table missing, perhaps due to user permissions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, authentication

I have an Application Server connected to a Database Server (running SQL Server 2014 Express)

I have the following query saved in saveEmails.sql on the Application Server

```
select 
    concat('<H3>Email sent: ',send_request_date,'</H3>',body) 
from
    msdb.dbo.sysmail_allitems 
where 
    send_request_date > dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) 
order by 
    send_request_date desc
```

I have the following saved in a batch file on the Application Server

```
sqlcmd -S <ip,port>  -y0 -U tomcat -P <password> -i saveEmails.sql -o
"C:\temp\saveEmailsOutput.htm"
```

I did `GRANT SELECT ON msdb.dbo.sysmail_allitems to TOMCAT`

When I run the query on the **database server** through SSMS, then I get all the rows in the table.

When I run the query on the **application server** through sqlcmd, then I only get the rows with sysmail_allitems.send_request_user=tomcat

How can I see all the rows and not just those with send_request_user=tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`msdb.dbo.sysmail_allitems` is a view and has [Row-level security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/granting-row-level-permissions-in-sql-server) implemented, which limits the user who is viewing to those rows which were executed by that user.

Run the query instead on `msdb.dbo.sysmail_mailitems` which is a table and does not have Row-level security implemented.

Note that SQL Server 2014 does not support row-level security on tables, but SQL Server 2016 does.